# How to route to the same nested state but have a different context?

Tags: ember.js, ember-old-router

I currently struggle to get a nested route to work, where one of the path elements is dynamic. That's the scenario I want to achieve:

The page contains the description of a project. Within the page is a tab menu to select different views. That should reflect in the URL as well. So I want to have different urls like:

```
url#/project1/info
url#/project1/status
url#/project1/...
```

To not repeat the `:project` parameter I added a nested project route that is not a leaf but only responsible for serialization/deserialization of the project itself.
Everything works fine as long as I use the initial project. But it can happen, that I want to link from one project to another project. That means the URL should change from `url#/project1/info -> url#/project2/info` and thus the view should change as well to display the infos about project2.

Sounds straightforward. However the deserialization method of the project route is not called when I link to project2 with an action helper

```
<a {{action changeProject context="App.project2" href=true}}>Go to project 2</a>
```

I guess that is because I am already in the info state. However how do I then propagate the context change? A simplified case you can find in the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jocsch/HYbZj/30/ or view it directly http://jsfiddle.net/jocsch/HYbZj/30/show/#/project1/info

```
Router: Ember.Router.extend({
    enableLogging: true,
    root: Ember.Route.extend({
        changeProject: Em.State.transitionTo('project.info'),                 
        index: Ember.Route.extend({
          route: '/',
         }),
         project: Ember.Route.extend({
           route: '/:project', 
           deserialize: function(router, params) {
              var proj = App.get(params['project']);
              router.get("applicationController").set("content", proj);
              return proj;
           },
           serialize: function(router, context) {
               return {project: context.id};
           },
           index: Ember.Route.extend({
              route: '/',
              redirectsTo: 'info'   
            }),                                    
            info: Ember.Route.extend({
              route: '/info',
              connectOutlets: function(router) {
                var ctrl = router.get('applicationController');
                ctrl.connectOutlet('project', ctrl.get('content'));
             }
         })
      })
   })
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need any custom serialization/deserialization.

One important missing thing in your code is the context passing in changeProject handler.

I would write the whole thing as follow:

**JS**

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Project = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    description: DS.attr('string')
});

App.Project.FIXTURES = [{
    id: '36',
    name: 'First project',
    description: 'My very first project'
}, {
    id: '42',
    name: 'Another project',
    description: 'My other favorite project'
}];

App.store = DS.Store.create({
    adapter: DS.fixtureAdapter,
    revision: 4
});


App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend();
App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'app-view'
})

App.ProjectsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend();
App.ProjectsView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'projects-view'
})

App.ProjectController = Ember.ObjectController.extend();
App.ProjectView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'project-view'
})

App.InfoController = Ember.ObjectController.extend();
App.InfoView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'info-view'
})

App.Router = Ember.Router.extend({
    enableLogging: true,

    root: Ember.Route.extend({
        index: Ember.Route.extend({
            route: '/'
        }),

        showProjects: function(router) {
            router.transitionTo('projects.index');
        }, 

        projects: Ember.Route.extend({
            route: 'projects',

            connectOutlets: function(router) {
                var applicationController = router.get('applicationController');
                applicationController.connectOutlet({
                    outletName: 'projectsList',
                    name: 'projects',
                    context: App.Project.find()
                });
            },

            index: Ember.Route.extend({
                route: '/'
            }),

            showProject: function(router, event) {
                var project = event.context;
                router.transitionTo('project.info', project);
            },

            project: Ember.Route.extend({
                route: '/:project_id',
                modelClass: 'App.Project',

                connectOutlets: function(router, project) {
                    var applicationController = router.get('applicationController');
                    applicationController.connectOutlet('project', project);
                },

                info: Ember.Route.extend({
                    route: 'info',

                    connectOutlets: function(router) {
                        var projectController = router.get('projectController'),
                            project = projectController.get('content');
                        projectController.connectOutlet('info', project);
                    }
                })
            })
        })
    })
});

App.initialize();
```

**Handlebars**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name='app-view'>
    <h1>Welcome to projects app!</h1>
    <a {{action showProjects}}>Projects home</a>
    <hr/>
    {{outlet projectsList}}
    <hr/>
    {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name='projects-view'>
    {{controller.length}} projects:
    <ul>
    {{#each project in controller}}
        <li>
            <a {{action showProject context="project"}}>{{project.name}}</a>
        </li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name='project-view'>
    <h2>Showing project <i>{{name}}</i></h2>
    {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name='info-view'>
    {{description}}
</script>
```

JSFiddle @ http://jsfiddle.net/MikeAski/fRea6/

Comment: Many thanks for your thorough answer Mike! There is a ton of goodies for me included. Like the fact that non-leaf states can contain a connectOutlets method...
But one thing still bugs me: Can you explain why your example fails when a href=true is added to the action helper in the templates? 

Uncaught Error: assertion failed: You must specify a target state for event 'showProject' in order to link to it in the current state 'root.projects.index

Comment: If you want to specify `href`, you have to declare `eventTransitions` map for states handling events. Updated fiddle to illustrate this: http://jsfiddle.net/MikeAski/fRea6/7/